# I have low storage and the first aid did nothing more than what I've already done

Tags: internal-storage, app2sd

but when I try moving apps to the sd card it only moved about 40mb of a1.5 gb game.  why will nothing go in my micro. I bought 32 gb so now I'm ticked it won't work

Comment: Please state android version, device, and if your rooted. It will help for possible solutions.

Comment: Additionally: what "first aid" are you referring to? I've just added the `app2sd` tag to your question. [Its tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/app2sd/info) holds some explanation and first aid you might wish to check.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't really asked a question but seems like you want a way to free up space on your phone.

---

### If you have lots of photos:

I would download [Google Photos](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.photos&hl=en). It can backup all of your photos on your device as long as you select the folders which you have folders in so you can go ahead and delete them off of your device. A benefit of this solution is you have access to your photos anywhere you can connect to your google account. There are other places to store your photos as well such as your computer or an external hard drive if you don't want the NSA/Google to know what you are up to.

---

### If you have lots of music:

Another space saving tip is if you use [Google Play Music](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.music&hl=en), which I would recommend as well, you can save all of your downloaded music from google play or your personal library using google play music to the SD card. Play music allows you to backup your music to google servers from your computer, then you can download them to your device or you can stream them from your device if you don't want them to take up space, but since you said you had an SD card you may want to opt to saving them on it from within the app. You can go to settings and change where your music is stored.

---

As for the reason you can't completely move an app to an SD card I speculate it may be because android needs certain files on your device and not held externally.

Wish you the best in your space endeavors.

Comment: Welcome to the Android Enthusiasts! What makes you think OP is making any photos at all, or playing music on the device? I see no indication for this in the question. Beside that, some formatting (paragraphs) would be great to make the post easier to read :)

Comment: Thanks sorry about that just trying to give some alternate views but you are right. That was my first post I will try to edit it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the update – looks waaaayyy better now :) And of course you are right, the question doesn't give much details (not your fault). Those two apps wouldn't be my choice, though – I'd rather backup my photos to my own computer, and prefer a music player where my music files stay mine ;) Might be worth mentioning that both apps are probably pre-installed on the device anyway. So let me give you an upvote for your effort, even if I disagree with the solution (but more for personal reasons ;)

Answer (score 0):

You Can Use apps to convert (Sdcard) to (Extsd) instead of moving apps.
Or You Can swap The (Sdcard) Whith (extsd).
Check out This Url It might be useful:

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2263436

Comment: Welcome to the Android Enthusiasts! Those are correct pointers. But please 1) mention that all this would require the device to be rooted, and 2) include at least the basics from behind the link. Otherwise, all information is lost if the linked post would be deleted. Can you please [edit] your answer accordingly?